# Removing no longer valid FCM tokens from a database

Tags: node.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, node-gcm

I am sending notification to mobile device for which I have fcm tokens.
On sending, I get a response that can for each fcm token have an error.
I want to remove the invalid tokens that for sure will no longer work, but keep tokens that may have failed this time and could still work in the future.

I am using the `node-gcm` package.

What are the possible values for the `error` field in the response of each token.
What checks on this value should I be making to only delete the permanently invalid tokens ?

```
    sender.send(gcmMessage, { registrationTokens: fcmTokens }, (error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        const failedTokens = fcmTokens.filter((_, index) => response.results[index].error != null);
        if (failedTokens.length) {
          // If there are failed tokens, check these to know whether we should delete them.
          
          this.clearUserFcmTokens(userID, failedTokens);
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer from the repo itself.

They recommend checking if the error matches `'NotRegistered'`.

I've modified the code to check `'NotRegistered'` and  `'InvalidRegistration'`:

```
    sender.send(gcmMessage, { registrationTokens: fcmTokens }, (error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        const invalidTokenErrorKeys = ['NotRegistered', 'InvalidRegistration'];
        const failedTokens = fcmTokens.filter((_, index) => response.results[index].error != null && invalidTokenErrorKeys.includes(response.results[index].error));
        if (failedTokens.length) {
          this.clearUserFcmTokens(userID, failedTokens);
        }
      }
    });
```

The values of the error field match the HTTP Code column from this link:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes

examples: `InvalidRegistration`, `NotRegistered`, `MessageTooBig`, `Unavailable` etc.

---

*Issue and response on the repo https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm/issues/360*

Answer (score 1):

The two most common error codes that indicate that the token should be removed are `messaging/invalid-registration-token` and `messaging/registration-token-not-registered`.

I recommend basing your logic on [this code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/fcm-notifications/functions/index.js#L88-L108) in the [functions-samples repo](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples).

Comment: I found those samples as well but with the node-gcm package my error is a String (so I can't do error.code)
Im thinking of just using those strings and compare to my error, but I m not sure if these keys will match what node-gcm is returning in the error value